# If element is on the sceen after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

Hello i'm trying to get if element is now on the screen when i scroll. I have this code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (checkVisible($('.tester'))) {
    $('.wrapper').css("background-color", "#4f4");
  } else {
    $('.wrapper').css("background-color", "#f44");
  }
});

function checkVisible(elm, eval) {
  eval = eval || "visible";
  var vpH = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
    st = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
    y = $(elm).offset().top,
    elementHeight = $(elm).height();

  if (eval == "visible") return ((y < (vpH + st)) && (y > (st - elementHeight)));
  if (eval == "above") return ((y < (vpH + st)));
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  height: 400%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f44;
}
.tester {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tester"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="tester"></div>
</div>
```

It works good< but if there are two or more div's with id or class tester it does not work with others. Why?
Thanks!

Ok, i edited code so now it is classes instead of id's. And everything goes the same - doesn't work correctly, only with the first "tester".

Comment: Do not use the same id for more than one element. It is not valid.

Comment: an `id` is supposed to be unique for the entire document. if you have two elements with the same `id`, your html is technically invalid. you should be using classes rather than id's in this case.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Look at this small lib http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

Comment: I know it, it just example, i use same classes but everything goes like with id's(

Answer (score 2):

A id have to be unique like xxxmatko says in the comment. I would use classes intead like: you change the id "wrapper" to class="wrapper"

In the css you can change the #wrapper to .wrapper

Comment: you are right, but it's just examples, with classes it goes the same as with id's.

Comment: thats not 100% right, cause id's are unique and classes you can use as much as you want.

Comment: yes, i edited example so now there are classes but everything goes same, work only first tester and other dont't(

Answer (score 0):

If the scrollTop of the element is greater than the -(height) of the element and less than the height of the browser window then it is on the page after scroll.

Also don't use duplicate IDs.

https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H93.html

Comment: thanks, but it's not the reason of the problem, the first tester works correctly, but second one not. in my project i have dynamically created wrappers and testers so there are many of them but works only first one.